# What is the number of all 2 digit numbers satisfying the given condition.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

**Question**: What is the number of all 2 digit numbers $n$ such that $n$ is equal to the sum of the square of the digit in its tens place and the cube of the digit in its units place?

**My work** :
$10x+y=x^2+y^3$ is the general form of all such numbers .
Also $x,y$ belong to integers 0-9 .
After this i proceeded by substituting $x=1$ to $x=9$ and similarly for $y$ too.( trial and error )
Neither it is a right approach nor  am I   getting an answer this way .

Answer (score 3):

We must have $y^3<n<100$, so $y\leq 4$. Also $10x-x^2=x(10-x)$, and this is at least $9$. So we must have $y^3-y=x(10-x)\geq 9$, meaning $y=3$ or $y=4$.

If $y=3$ then $x(10-x)=24$ whereas if $y=4$ then $x(10-x)=60$. Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 1):

You **will** get correct answers if you do trial and error on $y$ from 0 to 9. If $y=0$ or $y=1$ you get $10x=x^2$, which means $x=10$. This isn't legitimate answer, so move on to $y=2$ which gives $0=x^2-10x+6$. This quadratic equation doesn't have any integer solutions, so move on to $y=3$ and get $0=x^2-10x+24$. Solutions for this quadratic are $4,6$ which you can verify yield correct solutions. If $y>3$ then the resulting quadratic equations of $x$ don't have real roots (discriminant is negative), so that covers all possibilities of $y$.